# Best approach for a custom workflow

Tags: workflow, jquery, event-receivers, spservices

My team will soon be building a workflow for a list in SP2013.  The OOB approval workflow provides most of the needed functionality, but we need the approval flow set dynamically based on names captured in the list (some are text, some are look up, and some are persons).

There are many approaches promoted via blogs, forums suggesting P Designer, jQuery, SP project event receivers, SP app remote event receivers, etc.

Can anyone weigh in with their suggestions on how to decide which approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

Its for SharePoint Server 2013 or SharePoint online? For SharePoint online only limited options. As per your requirements SP Event Receivers is good for SP On-Promises environment.